# puedo hacer un array asociativo con claves pero sin valores para rellenarlos depues en PHP

Tags: php

algo asi es el objetivo

```
$prueba=array(patron=>'',usuario=>'')
```

con el fin de rellenar con valores en operaciones posteriores.
como puedo hacer esto de manera adecuada???
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para complementar la respuesta de `Federico Saenz` que es correcta, detallare un poco sobre el uso de arreglos.

Primero que todo dependiendo de la versión de PHP que estés usando puedes definir un arreglo así:

```
$arreglo = array('patron'=>,'usuario'=>);
```

o así a partir de PHP 5.4

```
$arreglo = ['patron'=>,'usuario'=>];
```

Ahora una ves definido puedes consultar el valor de las claves creadas

```
var_dump($arreglo['patron']) //Retorna NULL
var_dump($arreglo['usuario']) //Retorna NULL
```

También puedes modificar el valor asignado a las claves

```
$arreglo['patron'] = 666;
$arreglo['usuario'] = 'NekoOS';
```

He incluso añadir mas asociaciones

```
$arreglo['nuevo'] = 'dato insertado previamente';
```

Podrías imprimir en pantalla el arreglo completo

```
print_r($arreglo['usuario']);
/** 
Tendrías un resultado así:

    Array
    (
        [patron] => 666
        [usuario] => NekoOS
        [nuevo] => dato insertado previamente
    )
*/
```

Puedes encontrar mas información sobre el uso de arreglos y funciones para operar con arreglos en la pagina oficial de PHP, aquí te anexo dos vínculos que te podrían ser de utilidad:

- http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php
- http://php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php

Comment: muchas gracias Federico Saenz y NekoOs

Answer (score 0):

Sí, se puede. 
Pero acordate de ponerle las comillas a las keys para que sean del tipo string.

```
$prueba = array('patron'=>'','usuario'=>'');
```

Saludos.

Comment: hola gracias por escribir depues de unas pruebas no puedo insertaar valores en las claves se guarda en un nuevo campo, no se como rellenar en las claves???

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo del código, de cuando las estás generando? tené en cuenta que las keys no son case sensitive (o sea, son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas). Tal vez, sea eso lo que está pasando.